# Is there a relation to the dataPersistor/dbProvider reference and database table name?

Tags: magento2.3, naming-convention, datatable

I have inherited a custom module that is not working and not done yet.

I have a question regarding the UI form components and its relation to naming and usage (for instance: database table name/UI form dataSource/dataProvider)

Code where `dataPersistor` is used:

`/Save.php`:

```
$this->dataPersistor->clear('vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename');


$this->dataPersistor->set('vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename', $data);
```

Table name in `db_schema.xml`:

```
<table name="vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename Table">
```

Inside UI Component:

```
    <dataSource name="vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
```

Insie `di.xml`:

```
    <virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ReferenceSameAsTableName\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_referencesameastablename</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ReferenceSameAsTableName\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

## Question

What is the relation to these elements, basically I want to refactor and primarily rename these entities, especially the database table name.

Do the **dataPersistor / UI Component elements and table name** need to be the same?